# ADT updation error

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

How can I fix this error?

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.7.2120684 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.7.2120684)
  Software currently installed: Android Development Tools 21.0.1.v201212060256-543035 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 21.0.1.v201212060256-543035)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    ADT XML Overlay 23.0.7.2120684 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 23.0.7.2120684)
    ADT XML Overlay 21.0.1.v201212060256-543035 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 21.0.1.v201212060256-543035)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 23.0.7.2120684 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.7.2120684)
    To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [23.0.7.2120684]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Development Tools 21.0.1.v201212060256-543035 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 21.0.1.v201212060256-543035)
    To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [21.0.1.v201212060256-543035]
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Eclipse-->Help-->About Eclipse---->Installation Details
2. Select - Android DDMS, ADT, Android Hierarchy Viewer, Android Native                 Development Tools, Android TraceView and Tracer for OpenGL ES packages.
3. Uninstall all the plugins selected above.
4. Restart Eclipse
5. Install ADT from update site - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/